# Can you give an example of a local minimum with the following properties?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a twice differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with a local minimum at $x = 0$. I know that if (a) $f$ is $C^2$ and (b) $f''(0) > 0$, then it follows that $f$ is locally convex. I have seen an example of a smooth function $f$ with a local minimum at $x = 0$ such that $f''(0) = 0$, yet $f$ is not locally convex at $x = 0$. This proves the necessity of (b). Is (a) also necessary? Can you give an example of a twice differentiable but not twice continuously differentiable function $f$ with a local minimum at $x = 0$ such that $f''(x) > 0$ but $f$ is not locally convex at $x = 0$?

Thanks!